# Не работают комбинации shift+s и ctrl+s

Tags: windows, hotkeys

В windows 10 на ноутбуке не работают комбинации <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> и <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd>. Причем отдельно клавиша s работает отлично. так же работают другие комбинации, например <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> или <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>.
<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> и <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> не работают ни в одном приложении, ни в блокноте, ни, например, в ворде.

пробовал подключить клавиатуру - то же самое.

Может кто знает в чем может быть причина сбоя и как её решить?

Comment: может стоит посмотреть в настройках клавиатуры/горячих клавиш?

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. К сожалению так и не удалось выяснить точную причину. Сейчас то работает, то не работает. вероятно поможет переустановка или откат ОС, но пока что нет возможности это сделать. если найду причину - отпишусь в посте